# Reading a .PAM file format

Tags: c++, format, photoshop

I'm working on a picture editor for one of my projects, one request is that I support reading from and writing to a .PAM file. I've been looking on for it on wikipedia but haven't found much. Can someone help me understand how its structured and how might I to read it into memory using c++ so I can use and manipulate the pixels from the picture? I'm literally clueless.

Comment: this page describes the format rather well I think http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pam.html anything specifically you're having trouble with?

Comment: @PeterT Specifically I need to think of a way to extract pixel data from a string since I've read the file using RegEx. I kinda get that depending on a format it will depend how many bytes of  that string does each individual pixel component need. I've read BMP and PAM pixelData into a std vector of uint8_t